# How do you get the Super Rod in Pokémon Sword and Shield?

Tags: pokemon-sword-shield

Where and how can you get the Super Rod in Pokémon Sword and Shield?

Answer (score 12):

There is **no upgrade** of your fishing rod in Pokemon Sword/Shield. The Pokemon you can obtain during fishing are dependent on the location of the fishing spot, unlike previous games, where the quality of your rod also mattered.